# Angular Firebase Authguard redirect to path when user is logged

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, redirect, routes

just start to learn `ts / angular / javascript.` I want to make an app so i just found a git repo for an integration of **firebase** login inside an angular app. [This is the example.](https://github.com/code1ogic/Angular-Firebase-crud)

What i need to do is when a user access a specific path for instance `/account/dashboard`, if he is not logged in to be redirected to `/home`, of if he is logged in to redirect to `/dashboard`.

I have the following code inside my `auth.guard.ts` - I need to finish the `isLoggedIn()` method beside the line from where i get the value of **localstorage**. Any suggestions would be apreciated.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  
  constructor(
    public router: Router
  ){ }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginToken') || '{}');
    return (token !== null) ? true : false;
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(this.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigate(['home'])
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**UPDATED** Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76533519/5553846). Based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76518659/5553846). Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you actually don't need to implement this yourself. The @angular/fire library already has it done for you.

You simply need to import from here:

```js
import {AuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
```

and use in a route like so:

EDIT - forgot to include the declaration for the redirect

```js
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['your login page here']);

{
   path: 'admin',
   component: AdminComponent,
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
   data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin}
}
```

Note - this is as of @angular/fire 7.2.0.
If using a newer version the import location possible could have changed.

EDIT 2:

You'll also need to provide the auth module in the appropriate ngModule. This is the import you'll need:

```js
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

then, in your imports section for the module add this import:

```js
provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
```

Comment: Good point, i did all of that but i receive the following error.

```core.mjs:10162 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AuthGuard -> Auth -> Auth]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AuthGuard -> Auth -> Auth]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!```

Comment: @Rwi - edited the answer to include the necessary configuration you'd need in app.module.ts (or whatever module you're using)

Comment: Thanks for ur answare, i put the the code in app.module but i receive another error..

```core.mjs:10183 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AuthGuard -> Auth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.auth-instances -> [object Object] -> FirebaseApps -> FirebaseApps]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseApps!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AuthGuard -> Auth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.auth-instances -> [object Object] -> FirebaseApps -> FirebaseApps]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseApps!```

Comment: I would imagine you have a missing module from your imports. I would suggest you review the documentation for firebase and make sure you have the initiailze call for AngularFirebase as well as the provideFirebaseApp. Based on your error, I would assume you're missing this line: 
```typescript
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
```

Comment: Everything is setup properly, like in docs. I initialize the app like this in app.module.ts

```AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),```

With provideFirebaseApp() method .. the page is not loading, i receive 

```NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!```

I will read documentation again to see whats missing, even tho i think i cover everything.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks to @ye-olde-dev.

So in my **app.module.ts** i hade the firebase initialized like this:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

What i changed is i put what olde-dev suggsted instead of what i had above wich is:

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase))
```

And in the **Provides** i had only **AuthGuard** but i needed to provide the firebase options aswell so my provider from app.module.ts is like this:

```
providers: [AuthGuard, { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase }],
```

This is my **UPDATED** `app.module.ts` file:

```
......
import { AuthGuard } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ..................
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth())

  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  
})
export class AppModule {
```